# DataGridView items add to column 1 & column 2

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

How can I add my "PageElement2" to "column1" and "PageElement3" to "column2" ?

My code:

```
   Dim PageElement2 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElement2
        If (CurElement.GetAttribute("className") = "itemclassname") Then
            Dim row As String() = New String() {CurElement.InnerText}
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
        End If
    Next
    Dim PageElement3 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElement3
        If (CurElement.GetAttribute("className") = "itemclassnametwo") Then
            Dim row As String() = New String() {CurElement.InnerText}
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row) 
        End If
    Next
```

I have 2 column.

```
 Name
 Price
```

I want to add "PageElement2" items to "Name" column and "PageElement3" items to "Price" column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Dim Names As New List(Of String)
Dim Prices As New List(Of String)

Dim PageElement2 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElement2
    If (CurElement.GetAttribute("className") = "itemclassname") Then
        Names.Add(CurElement.InnerText)

    End If
Next

Dim PageElement3 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElement3
    If (CurElement.GetAttribute("className") = "itemclassnametwo") Then
        Prices.Add(CurElement.InnerText)

    End If
Next


For x = 0 To Math.Max(Names.Count, Prices.Count)
    If x < Names.Count AndAlso x < Prices.Count Then
        Dim row As String() = New String() {Names(x), Prices(x)}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: hm, "For x = 0 To Math.Max(Names.Count, Prices.Count)" I can't add more row name because "Error 1 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Max' accepts this number of arguments."

Comment: Try this: `Dim c As Integer = Math.Max(Names.Count, Prices.Count)` and then `For x = 0 To c`.

Comment: Thank you! How can I sort my prices(x)?

Comment: Try this: Dim c As Integer = Math.Max(Names.Count, Prices.Count) and then For x = 0 To c.  same error.

Comment: Know it's been a while ;)... Have you fixed this or...? Because i haven't been able to reproduce the error.